# Hashicorp Vault 307 redirect

Tags: docker, ssl, redhat, hashicorp-vault

I have already set up a Docker container running one instance but I don't understand what is different with my new installation and why I cannot connect. I currently get a 307 redirect.

Here is my config file:

```
{
        "listener": [{
                "tcp": {
                        "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",
                        "tls_cert_file": "/vault/config/certs/vault_crt.pem",
                        "tls_key_file": "/vault/config/certs/vault_key.pem",
                        "tls_disable": 0
                }
        }],
        "storage": {
                "file": {
                        "path": "/vault/data"
                }
        },
        "disable_mlock": true,
        "ui": true
}
```

I originally set the container up with tls disabled and ran operator init. I then enabled tls and restarted it.

I've gone back into the container and set the VAULT_ADDR=https://dns_name:8200. The dns_name resolves to the servers IP on which the docker container is running. When I run vault status I get a timeout. I assume because when I try from outside the container I get a redirect.

```
* About to connect() to <dns-name> port 8200 (#0)
*   Trying 172.31.168.219...
* Connected to <dns-name> (172.31.168.219) port 8200 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS: client certificate not found: ./vault_crt.pem
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=<dns-name>,OU=Department,O=Company,L=City,ST=County,C=GB
*       start date: May 26 10:19:44 2020 GMT
*       expire date: May 25 10:19:44 2025 GMT
*       common name: <dns-name>
*       issuer: CN=Company Issuing CA2,OU=IT,O=Company,C=GB
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: <dns-name>:8200
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
< Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-store
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Location: /ui/
Location: /ui/
< Date: Thu, 28 May 2020 12:42:18 GMT
Date: Thu, 28 May 2020 12:42:18 GMT
< Content-Length: 40
Content-Length: 40

< 
<a href="/ui/">Temporary Redirect</a>.

* Connection #0 to host <dns-name> left intact
```

Is this an SSL issue?

Comment: So just realised hitting the wrong URL outside the container. I can hit the site so why do I get a timeout int he container?

Comment: Curl works because it is on the host. Seems we have security in place when heading out off the container and back into the server url.

Comment: Can you do a `curl https://dns_name:8200/ui/`
Is it a self signed cert?

Comment: Probaly *not* an SSL/TLS issue. 307 is an HTTP code, which means the TLS negociation completed succesfully. Still looking for an answer though...